# How to authenticate into a Report Server Web Service?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, soap, reporting-services

I've installed SSRS 2017 locally. I'm trying to call Web Service with auto-generated SOAP client in VS2015 (which can be outdated, but I have no choice):

```
var cl = new ReportingService2010SoapClient();
cl.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
CatalogItem[] catalogItems;
var res = cl.ListChildren(new TrustedUserHeader {}, "/", false, out catalogItems);
```

The result is an exception below:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException occurred
>   HResult=-2146233087   Message=The HTTP request is unauthorized with
>   client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header
>   received from the server was 'NTLM'.   Source=mscorlib

I understand that my authentication attempt is incomplete, but I'm reading docs and examples for a while with no result.

Related docs:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2017/09/15/sql-server-reporting-services-2016-integration-with-an-application/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/accessing-the-soap-api

**UPDATE**: Also, I want to avoid messing with user name / password and want to re-use Windows mechanisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you first time configuring WCF client? Use Microsoft Service Configuration Editor (in VS: Tools > WCF Service Configuration Editor)!

With tool it was easy:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ReportingService2010Soap">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```